# how can i write the code for using threading concept in my ASP.Net Application using c#

Tags: asp.net, process, kill

I am developing ASP.NET Application using c#.net. In that i wrote code for sending a single mail to multiple Mail-Id's . 
     Hear i used For-loop for continues sending mail. 
    So, Hear my question is,
    1. I want to stop or pause sending mails , when i click "stop" button  ???.
    2. Is it possible to kill or pause the process of continues sending mails. ???

```
for (int i = 0; i < B.Length; i++)
                        {            
  if (txt_To.Text == "")
  {
   txt_To.Text = B[i].ToString();

    Methord1(); ////////////// UID ,PWD code

    int k = i + 1;
    Session["num"] = k;
    txt_To.Text = "";
    Label4.Text = Session["NUM"].ToString() + "Mail sent ...";

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly you have an emailing process you have started in a thread, and you want to be able to terminate the thread when a **stop** button is clicked. Is that correct?

The correct way to do this is to create a flag you can set on the threaded class to 'ask' it to terminate - force terminating a thread is a terrible terrible thing.

So, using your existing method I have added a bool in that determines whether the thread keeps executing. You will also need a `bool` in your class definition that runs all this code:

```
private volatile bool KeepRunning = true;

public void SendEmails()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < B.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!KeepRunning) return;         //<--- this is the new line

        if (txt_To.Text == "")
        {
            txt_To.Text = B[i].ToString();

            Methord1(); ////////////// UID ,PWD code

            int k = i + 1;
            Session["num"] = k;
            txt_To.Text = "";
            Label4.Text = Session["NUM"].ToString() + "Mail sent ...";

        }
    }
}
```

To be able to access the `KeepRunning` variable it needs to be marked as `volatile` to indicate you will access it from multiple threads. Now you can invoke the `SendEmails()` method in a separate thread, and you have a way of asking it to stop later on. T

If that is the case then you will need to retain a reference to the thread you have started the process in:

```
Thread MyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart("SendEmails"));
MyThread.Start();
```

Now the thread is running and looping.

To terminate the thread (in your 'stop' button handler or whatever) you just set `KeepRunning` as false, and the next time the loop executes it will drop out naturally on that line. You should also wait for the worker thread to rejoin the main thread before continuing:

```
KeepRunning = false;
MyThread.Join();
```

**Please note** this is all example code and hasn't been tested.